# Issue with PHP in Safari but not in Chrome

Tags: php, html, google-chrome, safari

I've earlier received an answer and solution in this post [here](//stackoverflow.com/questions/33955825/show-an-uploaded-image-in-php) and have therefore (almost) completed  my school task.

However, I have now found another problem when it comes to the choice of browser.

When I look at the overview.php in Safari, it looks like this:

[image: Link to Imgur]

As you can see in the image, whenever I use Safari to do the entries, it shows all the information as blank spaces in the first five rows, but the next one (in the bottom) has all the correct information.

When I use Google Chrome, I have no problems at all, as you can see here: 
[image: Link to Imgur]

So my question is, what part of my code is it that makes Safari do the empty entries?

**My code:**

*index.html* - the page where my standard HTML forms are.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="da">

<html>
  <head>

    <title>Mobiloversigten</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css">

  </head>

<body>

    <form name="formular" id="formular" method="post" action="process.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" autocomplete="on">

        <fieldset>

            <legend>Enhedsoplysninger</legend>
            <div><label>Producent: <input type="text" name="manufactor" id="manufactor" required="required" size="30"></label></div>
            <div><label>Produktnavn: <input type="text" name="product" id="product" required="required" size="30"></label></div>
            <div><label>Farve: <input type="text" name="color" id="color" required="required" size="30"></label></div>
            <label>Hukommelse:
                <div>    
                    <select size="1" name="memory" id="memory">
                        <option>8GB</option>
                        <option>16GB</option>
                        <option>32GB</option>
                        <option>64GB</option>
                        <option>128GB</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </label>
            <div><label>Skærmstørrelse <input type="number" name="displaysize" id="displaysize" min="0" step="0.1" size="30"></label></div>   
            <div><label>Produktbillede: <input type="file" name="productphoto" id="productphoto" required="required" size="30"></label></div>

        </fieldset>

        <div><input type="submit" id="ok" value="Indsend"><input type="reset" id="nulstil" value="Nulstil"></div>

    </form>

</body>

</html>
```

*process.php* - the page the entries from index.html is being saved.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="da">

<html>
<head>

  <title>Mobiloversigten</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css">

</head>

<body>

<div class= "logo">

    <img src="Mobilsiden.png" alt="Mobilsiden Logo" style="width:20%;height:20%;">

</div>

    <div class="boks">

        <h1>Enheden er registreret</h1>

    <div class="linie"></div><br>

        <div class="centerbuttons">
            <a href="index.html" class="myButton">Tilføj ny enhed</a>
            <a href="overview.php" class="myButton">Vis enheder</a>
        </div>

<?php

$manufactor = $_POST['manufactor'];
$product = $_POST['product'];
$color = $_POST['color'];
$memory = $_POST['memory'];
$displaysize = $_POST['displaysize'];
$productphoto = $_FILES['productphoto']['name'];


if($_FILES){
        if(strlen($_FILES['productphoto']['type'])==9)
        $name=$product . ".".$rest = substr($_FILES['productphoto']['type'], -3);
        else
        $name=$product . ".".$rest = substr($_FILES['productphoto']['type'], -4);

        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['productphoto']['tmp_name'], $name);

        }

$user_data = "$manufactor, $product, $color, $memory, $displaysize, $name \r\n";
$mobile_data = "Producent: ,Produktnavn: ,Farve: ,Hukommelse: ,Skærmstørrelse: ";

$fh = fopen("data.txt", "a")   or die("Filen kunne ikke oprettes");
fwrite($fh, $user_data)         or die("Kunne ikke skrive til filen");
fclose($fh);

$fj = fopen("mobile.txt", "w")  or die("Filen kunne ikke oprettes");
fwrite($fj, $mobile_data)       or die("Kunne ikke skrive til filen");
fclose($fj);

?>

</div>

</body>

</html>
```

*overview.php* - the page the entries from the text files that were saved earlier are being showed.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="da">

<html>

<head>

    <title>Mobiloversigt</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css">

</head>

<body>

    <div class= "logo">

        <img src="Mobilsiden.png" alt="Mobilsiden Logo" style="width:20%;height:20%;">

    </div>

    <div class="boks">

    <h1>Tilføjede enheder</h1>

    <div class="linie"></div><br>

    <?php

    $info = explode(",", file_get_contents("mobile.txt"));
    $retrieved_string = file_get_contents("data.txt");

    $retrieved_array = explode("\n", $retrieved_string);

    $count=count($retrieved_array)-1;

    for($y = 0; $y < $count; $y++){
    $user_data_array = explode(",",$retrieved_array[$y]);
    for($x = 0; $x <= 4; $x++){
        echo "<p>$info[$x]</p><p2>$user_data_array[$x]</p2><br>";
}       echo "<img src=\"$user_data_array[5]\"><br><br>";
        echo "<div><span class=\"linie\"></span></div><br><br>";
}


?>        

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I know that this is a very long post, but I just want to make sure, that the possible solution maker has the full overview of my code. I hope that isn't a problem.

As I am new to PHP, I would love to have a more understandable answer, if possible :-)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's not a php issue since php executes backend and is not impacted by the choice of browser - it simply delivers the output based on the request it receives. So your issue is html/css. Have you inspected the element in the browser using developer tools?

Comment: Thanks for your comment @Tristan. No I haven't really done that, since I'm not fully into that part of Safari. 
However. I can see that when I use Safari, it adds the blank spaces to my data.txt, so my overview.php pulls the blank spaces from that file.

Comment: And whats even more weird is that it doesn't happen all the time? When I test it right now, I don't get the error, so I'm really at a loss right now.

Comment: If you're finding that the user posted data can affect the display then you need to take measures to process or validate the posted data to ensure it is suitable. Eg you may remove html tags, strip whitespace, etc from the data the user enters in your form before you insert it into your text file.

Comment: Hmmm, so what would you exactly suggest @Tristan ?
I'm still confused why I get these blank spaces in the first place, since I don't do any submit without the forms being fully filled in. Safari just simply creates them by it self - I had some friends do some test with their own code which should be more or the less identical to mine, and they experience the same problem.

I have posted a screenshot of my data.txt file here on Imgur: http://i.imgur.com/5ZWMfE4.jpg

Comment: You could use regex to remove excess whitespace and line breaks `$string = preg_replace('/[ \t]+/', ' ', preg_replace('/\s*$^\s*/m', "\n", $string))`

Comment: How do I add that line of code to mine? Where should I put it? I've been doing some reading on regex, but I can't really understand it, probably do to me being new with PHP.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few problems with storing user submitted data in a text file without processing the data first. For example, if the user enters a comma `,` then it will break the `explode()` when you retrieve the data, or if the user enters a line break it will also cause problems.

You could use a function to clean the user submitted data of any characters that you identify are undesirable.

```
function cleanStr($str) {
    // remove extra whitespace
    $str = preg_replace('/[ \t]+/', ' ', $str);
    // remove linebreaks
    $str = preg_replace( "/\r|\n/", "", $str );
    // remove html tags
    $str = strip_tags($str);
    return $str;
}
```

Example of usage:

```
$manufactor = cleanStr($_POST['manufactor']);
```

If you store the data in the text file as json it will be more robust to user input, since commas in the text will not break it.

```
$user_data = array($manufactor, $product, $color, $memory, $displaysize, $name);
$user_data = json_encode($user_data)." \r\n";
```

And then save the data to the file the same way you currently are:

```
$fh = fopen("data.txt", "a")   or die("Filen kunne ikke oprettes");
fwrite($fh, $user_data)         or die("Kunne ikke skrive til filen");
fclose($fh);
```

And then decode the json when you want to display the data.

```
$user_data_array = json_decode($retrieved_array[$y]);
```